# Wrong vote count for question displayed in newest questions list

Tags: support, downvotes, upvotes

In the newest questions list, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044161/how-to-print-the-character-with-printf) appears to have a net vote count of -3:

[image]

However when you open it up, it's actually +3:

[image]

It's not due to the vote count having changed since I loaded the questions list, because the vote totals are +4/-1

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it the voting count *has* changed. Two people that downvoted changed their vote from down to up, changing the score from -3 to +1. An additional two votes then brings it to +3. You won't see changed votes in the vote counter. After changing their vote only one -1 downvote remains.

The voters probably changed their votes after the question was edited into shape.

The question list is cached; between you loading the cached version and the actual question those votes were changed.

Comment: I didn't realize it was possible to change your vote after you cast it. Mystery solved.

Comment: The off topic reason given(By Rizier123 and Grijesh Chauran) is completely wrong. I wonder why have they selected that option. What should we do in situations like this? Also, will commenting say, "@Rizier123" notify the user?

Comment: @CoolGuy: you can't notify the users that voted to close. Just vote to reopen but be prepared to re-close it as a dupe (someone already posted a dupe target in the comments, possible as result of a minority close vote).

Comment: Roger that. I voted to reopen the question.

Comment: @CoolGuy: reclosed now.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Why did I get a notification with "@CoolGuy: reopened, I cast the first vote to close as a duplicate" instead of your comment. I think it is because you've edited your comment. In that case, shouldn't the notification be changed too?

Comment: @CoolGuy: Notifications, once sent, don't get changed. Yes, I edited my comment.