# Why does the question list show an incorrect question score?

Tags: bug, question-lists, vote-count

When searching for `[sql] [sql-server-2008] is:question cast` I found this old, closed question:

- [SQL does replace and CAST on select affect the Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12692736/11682469)

In the question list, it looks like this

[image: Question in Question List]

The score is **1**.

When I look at the question, this is what I see

[image: Question itself]

The score is **2**.

I already noticed it yesterday and it was the same. I made sure no voting took place in the meantime.

I can't see the vote count, so I looked up the OP's [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1700703/jnoel10?tab=reputation) and found 4 relevant events:

1. 2012.10.02: Upvote
2. 2012.10.03: Downvote
3. 2012.10.05: Undownvote
4. 2018.01.30: Upvote

So the voting count is 2 UVs and 0 DVs, i. e. a score of 2 is correct.

**Why is the score displayed in the question list incorrect?**

---

It seems to be independent of search term or tab. I changed it a bit, e. g. searching the title directly or switching from *Relevance* to *Newest*.

I didn't find a related question. In this [case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284085/11682469) the voting count did change. And considering how old the question and activity on it is and also the time between me noticing it and writing the post now, I can't imagine it's caching.

Comment: Looks like an indexing error in the search engine metadata. That probably can be solved by voting on the post. Or just by editing it.